# get next immediate same date using php

Tags: php, date

1. i need to get immediate date like if i select date is `05` then output will be `2017-07-05` cause select date already passed
2. if i select `12` then output will be `2017-06-12` cause this date future date
3. final if i select previous date of current month then output will be next month same date and if i select future date of current month then output will be same month

i have tired but not working this

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$next_payment_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', $today));
```

or

```
$time = time();
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date("n", $time),date("j",$time)- 1 ,date("Y", $time)));
```

thanks in your advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more option:

https://3v4l.org/Me2Kh

```
$input = 12;
$day = date("d");

if ($input > $day){
    $date = date("Y-m-"). str_pad($input,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}else{

    $date = date("Y-m-",strtotime("+1 month")). str_pad($input,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo $date;
```

I use str_pad to keep two digit day number.

Comment: when i set $input = 12; // input date/number
then give error

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Correct.. Thank you, let's just call it a stupid mistake :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
<?php 

$day = '05';
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$supplied = date('Y-m-'.$day);

if($today>$supplied){
    $final = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($supplied)));
}
else{
    $final = $supplied;
}

echo $today;
echo '<br />';
echo $supplied;
echo '<br />';
echo $final;
```

> What I'm doing here -
>
> - Comparing the current and supplied date
> - Based on comparison, if supplied date is smaller, I'm adding 1 month else dislpaying the supplied date.

Comment: it is working but try to find common function with compare

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thank you for notifying about this issue. It can be resolved by using - `str_pad`

Comment: @RudrakshPathak or by not comparing strings ;-) Dates as strings and can create odd behaviour. If you only compare the day php will convert it to integer for the sake of the comparement. You could also strtorime() the $today and $supplied in the if() to make it compare correct

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$nextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
or $nextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($today));
```

Comment: maybe you're looking for something else but the code is working perfectly fine. $today gives today's date and nextDate gives next month's date.

Comment: please check my question.

Comment: my question was different

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help.

I would consider using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and it's [`add`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method for a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

```
$date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$date->add($interval);
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) are the supported `DateTimeZone` values. Make sure to set that to the applicable time zone.

Edit:
`DateTime` is mutable, so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
$selected_date = '2017-06-05';
$current = date('Y-m-d');
//echo $current;
if($selected_date < $current)
{
    $newDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($selected_date."+1 month"));
    echo $newDate; // gives 2017-07-05
}else if($selected_date > $current)
{
    $newDate = $current;
    echo $newDate; // gives 2017-06-07
}
?>
```

Comment: i will put only 07 or 12 etc not full date

Answer (score 0):

From what you described in the points at beginning of the question, you could achieve it this way:

```
$selectedDate = new DateTime('2016-06-05 00:00:00');
$now = new DateTime('now');
$now->setTime(0, 0, 0);

if ($selectedDate < $now) { // Selected date is in past

    // Set month and year to current
    $selectedDate->setDate(
        date('Y'), 
        date('m'), 
        $selectedDate->format('d')
    );

    // Add 1 month
    $selectedDate->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
} 

// If selected date is current or in future we do nothing

echo $selectedDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

For input `2017-06-05` it will return `2017-07-05` as expected, and for current or future date will return the date that was selected. Works also for any past date like `2016-04-05`